# How to use string in a new class in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, class, codeblocks

I am totally new to Code::Blocks and it seems strange to me. I am trying to define a string called `myString` inside a class called `myClass` but I am not able to define a variable of type `string` and also not able to call `iostream` inside my class. I need it for using `cout` and `cin`.

Comment: You seem to be missing the includes <iostream> and <string> or are not qualifying the types/objects with std::

Comment: thanks for your reply. I included the iostream in the .cpp file but still not able to implement cout. I can define int float but not able to define a variable of type string.

Comment: What I know is I am missing my mind after spending hours for implementing a simple string. :) This is when I admire visual studio and specially C# for being an intelligent IDE

Comment: @HosseinDolatabadi you have linking error... first create project and then add class and header file ... after that you can able to compile your file... I have just compile it and done successfully... code I used is at [here](http://pastie.org/5838141) but you have to make edit `#include <myClass.h>`

Answer (score 2):

Simple example of using string is ...

```
 // ide-Code::Blocks 10.05
 //  test.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class myclass{
    public:
        void assign_String(){
        string myString;
        const char *str2 = "StRiNg assign()";
        cout<<"str2, C string is: "<<str2<<endl;
        myString.assign(str2);
        cout<<"\n Assign String is "<<myString<<"\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    myclass mc;
    mc.assign_String();
    return 0;
}
```

For more about std::string follow reference [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html)

EDIT:- After viewing your comment you may have Linking error. So to solve this problem you have to create a new project and add file (class) to it. A class with no main() function can't be linked ... The example I do is at [here](http://pastie.org/5838141)

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is right but i found in code::bocks when I create a new class it would make two files one with .cpp format and the other .h in the .h file the prototype of the class should be defined and in .cpp the actual codes for variables and methods.
what I want to do is to use cout and cin inside my class file which is different from the file which contains the main method.

Comment: But I defined the path of the header file before and also called my class from the main() function. My problem is I am not able to call the iostream.h and consequently not able to call cout and cin predefined methods.

Comment: this is my .h file contents:
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class myClass
{
    public:
        myClass();
        virtual ~myClass();
        int showMessage(int);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H

Comment: and this is the .cpp file contents
#include "myClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

myClass::myClass()
{
    //ctor
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    //dtor
}

int myClass::showMessage(int message)
{
    return message;
}

Comment: the mnain file is:
#include <iostream>
#include <myClass.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;

    myClass myClassObj;
    cout<<myClassObj.showMessage(10)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: I just want to have a variable of type string in my class and also be able to use cout and cin in the class

Comment: I found that if I use the std amespace it would be possible to define an string inside a .cpp file.

Comment: yes thats right. I used this: using namespace std;  so now I can define an string but still not able to use cout and cin.